# Retrieve a record in custom settings without using SOQL query?

Tags: apex, customsetting

My question is how we retrieve a record in custom settings without using SOQl query?

Answer (score 2):

The following example returns a map of custom settings data. The getAll method returns values for all custom fields associated with the list setting.

```
Map<String_dataset_name, CustomSettingName__c> mcs = CustomSettingName__c.getAll();
```

The following example uses the getValues method to return all the field values associated with the specified data set. This method can be used with both list and hierarchy custom settings, using different parameters.

```
CustomSettingName__c mc = CustomSettingName__c.getValues(data_set_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

For hierarchical custom settings you can get the values without a query via this method:

```
MyHierarchicalSetting__c hs = MyHierarchicalSetting__c.getInstance();
```

The call also handles the prioritisation of user/profile/default settings. You get one object instance and then can access the fields.

For list custom settings (as LP_SFDC has illustrated) you can also get the values without a query using various techniques; for example this will get all values:

```
MyListSetting__c[] ls = MyListSetting__c.getAll().values();
```

You get a list of instances back.

See the [Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) documentation for more detail.